# Array's elements' attributes in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a newbie to Java. I have an array which includes sports IDs in `int` type. These IDs have sports name and calorie which burns if you do sport 1 hour. I want to add these attributes(name and calorie) through this array's elements. I am also reading a file that includes sports ID, name, and calorie information. I am splitting them by `\t`. It is splitting but the problem is, my implementation does not assign the attributes. I need to do this on `Sports class` not `Main class`. And I have to access this array and its attributes in other classes. If I give an example when I call `array[2].name` this must give me like `Basketball`. Or, `array[2].calorie` must give me `200`. I have tried in for loop and assign them like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    array[i].name = nameOfSport;
    array[i].calorie = calorieOfSport;
}




   import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sport {
    private int sportID;
    private String sportName;
    private int sportCalorie;
    public int[] sportArray = new int[0];

    public void readFileSport() {


        File file = new File("src/sport.txt");

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            int i = 0;
            String str;

            try {
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    int j = 0;

                    for ( String retval: str.split("\t")) {
                        if ( j == 0 ) {
                            System.out.println(retval);
                            sportArray = addElementArray(sportArray, Integer.parseInt(retval));
                            System.out.println(sportArray[i]);
                            j++;
                        } else {

                            if (j == 1) {
                               // System.out.println(retval);
                                setSportName(sportArray, retval, i);
                                System.out.println(sportArray[i].sportName);
                                j++;
                            } else if (j == 2) {
                                //System.out.println(retval);
                                setSportCalorie(Integer.parseInt(retval));
                                j++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Sport File could not find");
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sport file could not read!");
        }
    }

    public void assignFields () {

    }

    public void setSportID (int sportID) {
        this.sportID = sportID;
    }

    public void setSportName (int[] array, String name, int e) {
        array[e].sportName = name;
    }

    public void setSportCalorie (int sportCalorie) {
        this.sportCalorie = sportCalorie;
    }
    public void print() {
        int k = 0;
        while ( k < sportArray.length ) {
            System.out.println(sportID);
            k++;
        }
    }
    public static int[] addElementArray(int[] array, int newInt) {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }

        newArray[newArray.length - 1] = newInt;

        return newArray;
    }

    public int[] getSportArray() {
        return sportArray;
    }

}
```

Comment: And what's the current/expected behavior?

Comment: You should add what type `array` exactly is and also add the corresponding class in order for us to be able to help

Comment: You're missing the part of your code that parses the file, and the part that initializes the array.

Comment: @Mena The part that parses the file is unrelated, just hardcode the parsed file. ([mcve])

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I have editted

Comment: [mcve] please .

Comment: @user202729 maybe. The question lacks enough clarity that it might *become* relevant.

Comment: Sorry but what you described are requirements bit I don't see any description of problem which you are facing when you attempt to create code. What do you mean by "my implementation does not assign the attributes"? What you want to happen and what happens instead (are you getting error/exception/incorrect(unexpected) results)?

Comment: I HAVE ADDED MY CODE !

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have a class called `Sports` with

```
public class Sport{
    public String name;
    public int calorie;
}
```

Then you initiate them with

```
Sport[] sports = new Sport[]  // or your own split() to specify length
Arrays.setAll(sports, i->new Sport())
```

And this should be able to solve the problem.
You can also use `ArrayList` in which you could just add new elements while looping through the lines.

```
public static void readFileSport() {
    File file = new File("src/sport.txt");
    try {
        Scanner br = new Scanner(file);
        int i = 0;
        String str;

        try {
            while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] info=str.split("\t");
                System.out.println(info[0]);
                sportArray = addElementArray(sportArray, Integer.parseInt(info[0]));
                System.out.println(sportArray[i]);

                // System.out.println(info[1]);
                setSportName(sportArray, info[1], i);
                System.out.println(sportArray[i].sportName);

                //System.out.println(info[2]);
                setSportCalorie(Integer.parseInt(info[2]));
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Sport File could not find");
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sport file could not read!");
    }
}
```

When you only has 3 objects per line, it is actually easier this way.

Comment: But array must be include ID's in int type. name and calorie must be attribute of these elements of array

Comment: `Arrays.fill(s, new Sports());` will fill array with *single/same* instance of `Sports` class. So changes in that instance will be seen via all indexes. Maybe you meant something like `Arrays.setAll(s, i->new Sport())`.

Comment: @fokclac If you are looking for mapping `int` to `Sport` then instead of array you probably want to use `Map<Integer, Sport>`.

Comment: @Pshemo Map cannot being used :(

Comment: @fokclac Any particular reason for that? Maybe clarify it in your question because for now it is unclear what are you trying to achieve (at least IMO) and what problems you are facing.

Comment: @fokclac: Are you a JS programer in the past? This looks like JSON to me.

Comment: There is a rule that only arrays can be used. ArrayList, HashMap and so on cannot being used

Comment: @ZhaoYun when I wrote your code, it give me error like *Cannot resolve symbol 'sportCalorie'* and *Cannot resolve symbol 'sportName'*

Comment: did you initiated the Sport objects?

Comment: @fokclac, do you know, actually you could use ArrayList.toArray

Comment: @ZhaoYun I know, you are right, but only array can be used :((

Comment: @ZhaoYun What you mean *initiated* ? I did not understand

Comment: Like Object o=new Object()